# Finding top payment types by total value and total number of transactions

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

I have the table, **Payments**, with the following data:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE payments (
  Transaction_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Business_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Payment_Amount DECIMAL(25,2),
  Payment_Type VARCHAR(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (Transaction_ID)
 );

CREATE TABLE business_results (
  Business_ID INT NOT NULL,
  Top_Payment_Type_by_Dollar_Amount VARCHAR(6),
  Top_Payment_Type_by_Transactions VARCHAR(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (Business_ID)
);

INSERT INTO payments (Transaction_ID, Business_ID, Payment_Amount, Payment_Type)
  VALUES (1,2, 3.00, 'CASH'),
    (2,1,15.00,'CREDIT'),
    (3,4,5.00,'CASH'),
    (4,3,31.00,'CASH'),
    (5,4,2.00,'CREDIT'),
    (6,2,25.00,'CASH'),
    (7,2,30.00,'CREDIT'),
    (8,3,16.00,'CASH'),
    (9,1,7.00,'CREDIT'),
    (10,4,4.00,'CREDIT');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from payments;

| Transaction_ID | Business_ID | Payment_Amount | Payment_Type |
| -------------- | ----------- | -------------- | ------------ |
| 1              | 2           | 3              | CASH         |
| 2              | 1           | 15             | CREDIT       |
| 3              | 4           | 5              | CASH         |
| 4              | 3           | 31             | CASH         |
| 5              | 4           | 2              | CREDIT       |
| 6              | 2           | 25             | CASH         |
| 7              | 2           | 30             | CREDIT       |
| 8              | 3           | 16             | CASH         |
| 9              | 1           | 7              | CREDIT       |
| 10             | 4           | 4              | CREDIT       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hB1tDetfRiam8Wm1crxdwQ/1)

Transaction type consists of either 'Credit' or 'Cash'

I am trying to create a query with the following results:

- Column 1: Business_ID
- Column 2: States which payment type had the **largest total dollar amount** by sum of payment type
- Column 3: States which payment type had the **most number of transactions**

Based on the data provided, the results should be the following:

---

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Business_ID | Top_Payment_Type_by_Dollar_Amount | Top_Payment_Type_by_Transactions |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|           1 | CREDIT                            | CREDIT                           |
|           2 | CREDIT                            | CASH                             |
|           3 | CASH                              | CASH                             |
|           4 | CREDIT                            | CREDIT                           |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

---

How would I go along in doing this in a **single** MySQL query?

--

Comment: Thank you for showing me on proper formatting. I've updated my question and utilized Fiddle for easier replication.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the desired result, as text - not an image!

Comment: Also, you should really specify your primary key. A table without at least one unique key isn't really a table.

Comment: Done and done! I added a new column called "Transaction_ID" as my primary key in this example.

Answer (score 0):

So, the first part of the problem can be solved like this...

```
SELECT x.business_id
     , x.payment_type
  FROM payments x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT business_id
            , MAX(payment_amount) payment_amount 
         FROM (SELECT * FROM payments) n
        GROUP  
           BY business_id
     ) y 
    ON y.business_id = x.business_id 
   AND y.payment_amount = x.payment_amount
 ORDER
    BY x.business_id;
```

...the subquery *n* isn't strictly necessary - I could (and should) have just used `FROM payments`, but this way it provides a clue to solving the next part of the problem, where essentially, you just need to replace n with...

```
SELECT business_id
     , payment_type
     , SUM(payment_amount) total 
  FROM payments 
 GROUP 
    BY business_id
     , payment_type;
```

... and slightly tweak the main join clause

Comment: I may have made the first part of the problem unclear. What I meant to find was the payment type that has the largest total sum of money for each business. In this case, it looks like your query provided the largest sum of money in a single transaction rather than a whole sum of the payment type.

Comment: I tend to work on the assumption that if my answer returns the same result as your, then either mine is right, or your sample data set is wrong! (i.e. insufficiently representative)

Comment: Fair enough. My mistake as I went back and took a look at the data and noticed discrepancies. The data has been updated as well as the requirements wording.